# How to convert a byte in two's complement form to it's integer value? C#

Tags: c#

Given a byte in two's complement form, I am attempting to convert that byte into it's decimal representation. For example the `byte` `10000000` I would need to convert to `-128` and the `byte` `01111111` I would need to convert to `127`. I've looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812501/twos-complement-conversion), but I haven't been successful with taking one of the answers and making it work for me.

How do I go about doing the conversion?

CLARIFICATION: I'm trying to convert a `byte` in two's complement form into an `int` and not a `string` representation of a binary value into an `int.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert binary string into integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149728/convert-binary-string-into-integer)

Comment: Use this: int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0); where bytes is your byte array :)

Comment: int value = (sbyte)byteval;

Comment: `11111111` in two's complement is not -128.  Are you sure that's the correct test case?  Could you add more test cases to the question?

Comment: The OP is confused about what two's complement encoding means.  -128 in two's complement is 10000000 in base 2.

Comment: @HansPassant indeed. This works as you described `unchecked {((sbyte)0b01111111).Dump();}` with `10000000`

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the help. I should clarify that I am starting with an unsigned byte in two's complement form. So -128 is represented as `10000000` and when trying to cast this to an `sbyte` the value is too large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static int ConvertTwosComplementByteToInteger(byte rawValue)
{
    // If a positive value, return it
    if ((rawValue & 0x80) == 0)
    {
        return rawValue;
    }

    // Otherwise perform the 2's complement math on the value
    return (byte)(~(rawValue - 0x01)) * -1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I downvoted before I checked this thoroughly. Although it is correct it's a bit complicated. If you edit your answer I'll be able to remove the downvote. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to cast it to `sbyte`

```
byte b = 0b10000000;
sbyte s = (sbyte)b;

Console.WriteLine(s); // -128
```

You can convert this to an Int32 value and encapsulate this with

```
public static int ByteToInt32(byte value)
{
    return (sbyte)value;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried with the OP's example. Just realized it's wrong